# How to compute two aggregate functions with Java streams?

Tags: java, stream, aggregate-functions

I have a list of "Request" objects (id, amount, price) like this

```
List<Request> requests = Arrays.asList(
        new Request(id++, 20, 59.28),
        new Request(id++, 10, 61.23),
        new Request(id++, 30, 60.67),
        new Request(id++, 25, 60.16),
        new Request(id++, 60, 59.67));
```

and I want to compute two metrics - sum(amount) and sum(amount * price) - in one iteration. I need them to calculate the average price: sum(amount * price) / sum(amount).

Taking into account that I want to use Java 8 streams, the only variant that I found is mapping value into Pair object and implementing a custom consumer:

```
static class Aggregate implements Consumer<Pair<Double, Double>> {
    private double count = 0L;
    private double sum = 0L;

    public double average() {
        return count > 0 ? sum/(double) count : 0;
    }

    public void combine(Aggregate other) {
        count += other.count;
        sum += other.sum;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Pair<Double, Double> data) {
        this.count += data.getLeft();
        this.sum += data.getLeft() * data.getRight();
    }
}

Double avgPrice = requests.stream()
        .map(e -> Pair.<Double, Double>of(e.getAmount(), e.getPrice()))
        .collect(Aggregate::new, Aggregate::accept, Aggregate::combine)
        .average();
```

This approach looks quite messy - we have to create extra Pair object for each entry :(

Does anyone know a better solution?

Comment: Is it really *that* important to you that you only iterate once? This sounds like one of those "simplicity vs efficiency" balances... do you have evidence that if you do it in two passes it will be too slow?

Comment: Why does your Aggregate accept instances of Pair, instead of simply accepting instances of Request? What's the point in transforming a Request to a Pair?

Comment: @JBNizet you are right, my mistake.

Comment: Also note that `sum` should be a `double`, not a `long`.

Comment: @JonSkeet, anyway - why should we do two passes if the problem can be solved in one pass?

Comment: Because the code ends up being simpler that way... it's as simple as that. The absolutely-most-efficient way of doing something is very rarely the simplest way of doing it.

Comment: @JonSkeet, agree - sometimes it makes sense. But that is an academical question )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  You'll need the custom aggregation, but not the Pair:

```
 static class Aggregate {
   private long count = 0L;
   private double sum = 0L;
   double average() { return sum / count; }
   void merge(Aggregate other) {
     count += other.count;
     sum += other.sum;
   }
   void add(int count, double value) {
     this.count += count;
     this.sum += count * value;
   }
 }
}

requests.stream().collect(
   Aggregate::new,
   (aggr, request) -> aggr.add(request.getCount(), request.getPrice()),
   Aggregate::merge)
 .average();
```

And you don't actually need to implement `Consumer`.

Though honestly, the multi-pass solution is probably very nearly as fast and much simpler...

```
requests.stream()
      .mapToDouble(request -> request.getCount() * request.getPrice())
      .sum()
   / requests.stream().mapToLong(Request::getCount).sum();
```